# Chrome extension: how to let chrome.browserAction.setIcon apply to all tabs?

Tags: google-chrome-extension, toggle, sendmessage

I made an extension for modifying URLs in webpages. This function itself is simple and works fine, so I will not explain this part.

The problem is with browser action icon. I want the icon to change to an "on-icon" or an "off-icon" when I toggle it by clicking the browser action. So far it responds OK to my click. But when I refresh the webpage, it automatically goes back to its default icon, rather than staying at the on or off state.

I tried to add a sendMessage line to content script to tell the background.js to refresh the icon each time the page is loaded, but it does not work.

See the scripts below. What is wrong?

Here is the background.js:

```
var toggle = true;
chrome.browserAction.onClicked.addListener(function(tab) {
  toggle = !toggle;
  if(toggle){
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png", tabId:tab.id});
            }
        else{
    chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id});
            }
});

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.cmd == "isiton") {
        sendResponse(toggle);
    }
});
//The above works fine.

chrome.extension.onMessage.addListener(
function (request, sender, sendResponse) {
    if (request.cmd == "refreshicon") {
if(toggle){
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "on.png", tabId:tab.id});
        }
    else{
chrome.browserAction.setIcon({path: "off.png", tabId:tab.id});
        }
}
});
//This part does not work.
```

And here is the content.js:

```
chrome.extension.sendMessage({ cmd: "isiton" }, function (response) {
    if (response == true) {

var anchors = document.getElementsByTagName("a");

for (var i = 0; i < anchors.length; i++) {
    anchors[i].href = anchors[i].href.replace(/(resume\/showresumedetail\/\?res_id_encode\=[^\&]*)[^\"]*/g, "$1")
}
    }
});
//The above works fine.

chrome.extension.sendMessage({ cmd: "refreshicon" });
//This part does not work.
```

=======
Updated - This is my solution after taking your advice:

Thank you Makyen!

I tried it. Yes, the problem is that I restricted the function to a tab. Therefore I removed all the "tabId:tab.id" part, so that the icon is set for the entire chrome window rather than an individual tab. Now, I'm very happy with the result!

I also changed "chrome.extension" to "chrome.runtime". I'm not aware what is the difference between them. Anyway, it is good to use the new term.

According to your suggestion regarding the title and presentation of my question, I editied it, hoping it can be helpful to other users searching for such topics.

Comment: 1. Are you using a background page or an event page?  2. Why not have just one `addListener` in background.js?  (3. Don't write `response==true` just write `response`.)

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: include a [mcve] that duplicates the problem. For Chrome extensions or Firefox WebExtensions this almost always means including your *manifest.json* and some of the background, content, and/or popup scripts/HTML. Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working the way I want?") must include: (1) the desired behavior, (2) a specific problem or error and (3) the shortest code necessary to reproduce it *in the question itself*. Please also see: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Use `chrome.runtime` for `sendMessage` and `onMessage`. The `chrome.extension` versions of those are deprecated or only supposed to be used in other circumstances.

Comment: You are setting the state of the icon independently for each tab based on a variable, `toggle`, which you are only tracking for the entirety of your extension (i.e. all tabs). That is going to be broken in some way. You need to either A) Have the state be the same for all tabs, and set the icon for all tabs, or B) track the state for each tab.

Comment: Thank you, Makyen. I tried your adivce (A). It worked! I added the solution at the end of my question. Really appreciate your help!